# Having trouble installing Ubuntu onto VirtualBox

Tags: software-installation, virtualbox, 22.10

I'm on Windows 10 64 bit OS, running the current versions of VirtualBox and Ubuntu as a virtual machine. It always goes through the full first startup, but never shows the user login screen. Here's the error message:

```
Failed to set the global VirtualBox extra data for key GUI/GuestControl/FileManagerVisiblePanels to value {}.

Callee RC:RPC_E_CANTCALLOUT_ININPUTSYNCCALL (0X8001010D)
```

[image: added a screenshot of the errors and surrounding code on startup]

Comment: **Welcome to the Ubuntu Ask community.** From your issue, it sounds to me like this is more about a Windows configuration and less about the Ubuntu OS. So, I don't think you're going to find too much support for Windows here. My suggestion would be to work directly with the [Virtualbox forum](https://forums.virtualbox.org/index.php), where you'll likely get better results.